# rails 3.2 BigDecimal and floating point numbers comparison returns absurd result

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bigdecimal

I'm having problems working with BigDecimal in Rails 3.2.3 and ruby 1.9.3p362
the following sequence of number comparisons output absurd results

```
1.9.3-p362 :060 >   b = BigDecimal.new('620.56')
=> #<BigDecimal:68665e0,'0.62056E3',18(18)>

1.9.3-p362 :061 > b <= 620.56
=> false
1.9.3-p362 :062 > b > 620.56
=> true

1.9.3-p362 :063 > (b - 620.56) > 0
=> false
1.9.3-p362 :064 > (b - 620.56) == 0
=> true
```

in other words, this is telling that:

```
B > A
```

and

```
B - A == 0
```

what am I missing ?

Comment: Interesting! I see the same thing in 1.9.3-p448. I set b = numbers from 620.55 to 620.58 and tested if b == number. 620.55 test gives true, 620.56 gives false, 620.57 gives false, 620.58 gives true!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to the wonderful world of Floating Point Arithmetic.

[This website](http://floating-point-gui.de/) gives a good introduction of how and why (check the [Basic Answers](http://floating-point-gui.de/basic/) first), but what it comes down to is:

Computer are not very accurate when it comes to floating point numbers. Rounding errors are everywhere, so you have to be careful what you do.